# Converting csv file to image

Tags: pandas, image, csv

I have [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/sachinpatel21/az-handwritten-alphabets-in-csv-format) consist of pixel values of letter images. Every row has 1+784 values corresponding to label(first column) and pixel values(28x28=784).

How can I get 784 pixel values from every row with pandas and so I can convert array to image?

I tried the code below but the elapsed time for one image is not satisfying. If someone has faster, please answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

file = 'dataset.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file)
labels= data['0']
del data['0'] # delete labels

images = []
for i in range(data.shape[0]): # row
    entire_row = []
    t = time.time()
    for j in range(data.shape[1]): #column
    #    print(data.ix[i,j])
        entire_row.append(data.ix[i,j])
    images.append(entire_row)
    print("Elapsed time: {}".format(time.time()-t))
```

Output :

```
Elapsed time: 0.7288131713867188
Elapsed time: 0.7584271430969238
Elapsed time: 0.7338221073150635
...
```

Comment: If you want people to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them... so rather than hope anyone will download your 82MB file and unzip it and get a couple of lines to test with, maybe consider leaving the reference to the full dataset in your question, but pasting in a line or two of sample data for folks to experiment with. Just a thought.

Comment: The dataset is very big to prepare a test data. Also I described the general shape of the dataset, if it's not explanatory, you can make edit. I asked this question because I have don't any experience in pandas.

Comment: *"The dataset is very big to prepare a test data."* - that is my point! If it's too much trouble for you, who has a vested interest in solving the problem, to make a test data set, imagine how motivated StackOverflow users will be to make it.

Comment: Until preparing a test data, I can solve the problem myself (I searched a bit and there is no such kind of solution of this problem). I'm trying now, if no one help, then I can answer my question when I solve, because I need this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaggle has a great source of public Kernels people have posted so you can get an idea how to use the data sets in a model and work with them to train / test.

For example:
[CNN using keras - using CSV - Accuracy 99.82%](https://www.kaggle.com/codhek/cnn-using-keras-using-csv-accuracy-99-82)

Here is one specifically where they convert the rows to images as you have requested:
https://www.kaggle.com/sachinpatel21/csv-to-images